# When listening to server, it says server is not defined. Is there another way to listen to a server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm setting up a new server in Node.js, and the terminal keeps on saying Reference Error: server is not defined. Is there another way to setup a server? Or is there a syntax error?

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log(req)
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Where in that code is there a variable named `server`? In that snippet there is absolutely nothing defined or assigned to a variable named `server`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created server with http.createServer((req,res)) but you are listening to server variable, which not defined in your code. So you can either defined it or use listen by chaining it.

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log(req)
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Or

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log(req)
}).listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

you may try this way also.

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log(req)
}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: This is a much better approach. Thank you @javapedia.net

Answer (score 1):

You just need to declare a variable to hold the server value

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log(req)
});

server.listen(3000);
```